# How to access a property inside a generic?

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have a base class that always has the property of `.Balance`. I need to iterate through a list of classes and add the balances together. This is all fine and dandy, but there are two derived classes, `Assets` and `Liabilities` that can also be passed. How can I make this work generically without overloading `GetTotalBalance`? What's more, how can I require the `<T>` to be derived from the class `AccountBase`, which would guarantee the inclusion of the `.Balance` property? Is that possible?

```
private float GetTotalBalance<T>(List<T> accountList) where T : class
{
    float totalAssets = 0.0f;
    for (int assetIndex = 0; assetIndex < accountList.Count; assetIndex++)
    {
        totalAssets += accountList[assetIndex].Balance;
    }
    return totalAssets;
}
```

Comment: `where T : AccountBase` ??

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for generic constrants:

```
where T : YourBaseClass
```

Or, make the function non-generic, and accept an `IEnumerable<YourBaseClass>` (since interfaces are covariant).

While you're at it, change the function to

```
return accounts.Sum(a => a.Balance);
```

Comment: Too slow with a response, what he said :-)